# How to use admin interface if I have no application?

Tags: django

I am creating a Django based app and I'd like to put everything under the root in the following structure:

```
/path/to/my/app/
    settings.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    admin.py
    ...
```

One problem that I run into is the admin interface doesn't include whatever models I have that are registerd in admin.py usin

```
admin.site.register(models.MyModel)
```

Usually that's done by using auto discover in urls.py, but now I have no registered "app", the auto discover doesn't work anymore. Is there anyway I can still use the admin interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django simply doesn't work without apps. They're the fundamental building block of a Django site. A whole range of things, not just the admin, will fail to work. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe I am thinking it wrong but my entire site is dedicated to one app. I don't want the extra dir structure.

Comment: It's only one extra directory from what you're asking for.  Why are you worried about it?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the app in the django-style directory structure will make your project easily extensible if you decide to add functionality later.